# Looking for copies of "Analog Science Fiction & Fact"

Tags: short-stories, publishing

What are good sources for specific back issues of publications like Analog?

I've already looked in the normal places (Amazon, Google, etc.) but I suspect I'm going to need to search some kind of specialty source but I don't know of any. I'm not looking for discount sources and am even willing to pay a slight premium if that's what it takes.

I'm looking for general answers because that will be of value to others and I'm more than willing to do the rest of the leg/mouse work. The details if anyone cares: I'm looking for a three part story that was published in late '08 and so far I've only found the 2nd of the three.

Comment: It is always reasonable to contact the publisher about remaindered copies, though there is no guarantee that they have any.

Comment: What you need is to look for a used science fiction book dealer - some of them also deal in magazines. Also, check out the FAQ from the Analog web site: https://www.analogsf.com/information/faq.shtml

Comment: @Donald.McLean That FAQ looks like a pretty thorough answer, I recommend posting it as an answer (with a nice quote block of the relevant text).

Comment: @Donald.McLean: That's what I'm asking after, do you have any to recommend that are known to have a good selection?

Comment: Is the serial David Palmer's *Tracking*? As of last month two of the issues were [available](http://www.amazon.com/gp/forum/cd/discussion.html/ref=ntt_mus_ep_cd_tft_tp?ie=UTF8&cdForum=Fx15J8UENBFAF8B&cdThread=Tx2D9RQGAWTVXVF) from the publisher.

Comment: @sjl: yes. I've put in an e-mail to them. OTOH it sounds like they only have pt. 2 and 3 but not pt. 1. Better than nothing.

Comment: Try Uncle Hugo's & Uncle Edgar's Bookstores - Science Fiction, Fantasy, Mystery  in Minneapolis.
www.unclehugo.com/‎

Comment: Ebay is a good source as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to look for a used science fiction book dealer - some of them also deal in magazines. Also, check out the FAQ from the Analog web site: analogsf.com/information/faq.shtml

> Do you sell back issues?
>
> Analog sells recent back issues directly from the editorial offices. Simply send an email to analog@dellmagazines.com requesting the issues you'd like. We will then get back to you with availability, prices (generally cover price with ship costs), and where to send your payment.
>
> For older back issues, you can try posting a message to our forum to see
>   if any other readers would be willing to part with the issue(s) you want, or find a local SF shop that sells back issues, or check out conventions.
>
> You may also want to check out online auction sites such as eBay. A fair number of back issues have been surfacing there.

A list of specific businesses follows (not included because of locality rules).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like "Tracking" by David R. Palmer, July/Aug, Sept, & Oct 2008. (I liked it some, but I thought it was just "Emergence" again with slightly different characters. I liked "Emergence" a lot.)

Can you send me a private email? My user name is 'jpatmcgee1' with the domain being the big company whose name starts with 'g'. I'm about to get rid of my collection. I'll snail-mail that story to you and you can send me the postage later.

Anything else you're interested in?

Any anyone else who is interested, but I'll give bcs first crack at anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

http://www.abebooks.com

http://www.oldsfbooks.com